# Flutter: Location enabled/disabled stream listener

Tags: flutter, stream, location

I'm trying to achieve on of my screen to listen whenever a setting is on and off using stream.
For internet connectivity, I used [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity),  I manage to use the stream method onConnectivityChanged to listend on changes on network (turn off wifi, mobile mode, wifi moded). For location service enabled/disable, I'm trying to achieve same function but can't but any package or exisiting approaches for location enabled/disabled listener. Is there any packages/methods/approaches out there for flutter?

Answer (score 1):

you can check out the [Flutter Geolocator Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator).
In the docs there is the [getServiceStatusStream()](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator/latest/geolocator/Geolocator/getServiceStatusStream.html) which does that